# Subring of an artinian unital ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there any unital artinian ring  such that it have a unital subring isomorphic to itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K$ be any field. The rational function field $K(t)$ has proper subfields which are isomorphic to $K(t)$, e.g. $K(t^2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any purely transcendental field extension $K\subset L$ with infinite transcendence basis $S$.  Then any subset $S' \subsetneq S$ with $|S'| = |S|$ yields an intermediate field $K\subset L' \subsetneq L$ with $L' \cong L$.

For example, $\mathbb{R}$ contains many subfields with this property (take any purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with infinite transcendence degree).

Comment: I don't think the statement about $\mathbb R$ is correct, because this would imply that $\mathbb R$ has nontrivial endomorphisms, which it doesn't, right? (Consequently $\mathbb R$ must not be purely transcendental.)

Comment: @BrentKerby You're quite right.  My new edit should be correct.